# PHP MySQL Order by multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am looking to create an order based on multiple columns in my table - all date related. For example: my columns are: `fee_due`, `fee_2_due`, `fee_3_due` - they all contains results of various dates. However, I want to create an order combining all columns, so `fee_due` might be `2012-11-03`, `fee_2_due` might be `2012-11-01` and `fee_3_due` might be `2012-11-02`.

My query needs to be:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
ORDER BY [date] DESC
```

... whereby the dates from the 3 columns join to form one order, regardless of what column they are in.

Hope that makes sense and thanks in advance.

Comment: `SELECT *
FROM table_name
ORDER BY fee_due, fee_2_due DESC`

Comment: Were you looking to order by the earliest (or latest) date of the three columns? So in your example, the selected column to use as the sort would be fee_2_due, however it could be fee_3_due for another row?

Answer (score 14):

Additionally you can:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
ORDER BY fee_due ASC,fee_2_due DESC,fee_3_due DESC
```

You can sort each column independently according to your need.

Answer (score 3):

I used the following to make it work:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY camp1 ASC, camp2 ASC, camp3 DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
ORDER BY fee_due,fee_2_due,fee_3_due DESC
```

Comment: In this instance would it create the order of: 2012-11-03 - 2012-11-02 - 2012-11-01 ?

Comment: Yes this should give expected result

Comment: `fee_2_due` is used to break the tie for rows with the same `fee_due`, `fee_3_due` is used to break the tie when `fee_due` and `fee_2_due` are the same. Is that what you want?