# PHP order by two columns added together

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have put so much research into this but most posts don't understand what i mean. How can you do multiple database columns in a query?

I have a table called users and two columns called wallet_cash and bank_cash and i then have a table in my admin cp with most cash. I want to do it ORDER BY wallet_cash + bank_cash

Order by them two variables added together but how can i do this?

My attempt so far

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY wallet_cash + bank_cash desc LIMIT 4");
```

But this just puts the same result as and doesn't add the bank_cash so like your just putting ORDER BY wallet_cash

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13629571/php-mysql-order-by-multiple-columns

Comment: This is just doing it order by? I want to add the to columns together they are booth int numbers

Comment: First of all, you should use `mysqli_query()` as `mysql_query()` is deprecated as of PHP 5.5. Although this should work, can you provide a result? and maybe also put `wallet_cash + bank_cash` in the SELECT clause to see what it is doing.

Answer (score 2):

Add the two fields together in your select and designate it to another value using `AS`. Then, you can order by the newly created column.

```
$result = mysql_query(SELECT *, (wallet_cash + bank_cash) AS total_cash FROM users ORDER BY total_cash desc LIMIT 4");
```

Comment: you did not read the part where OP states that those columns are in 2 different databases

Comment: @GGio - Where does it say there are two databases?

Comment: `and i then have a table in my admin cp with most cash` and `How can you do multiple database columns in a query?` unless I misunderstood his english.

Comment: Multiple database columns = multiple columns from one table in one database as far as I understand.

Comment: @GGio . . . I read that as multiple columns, not multiple tables.  Plus, the OP implies that the query in the question does run; it just doesn't return the right results.

Comment: I see, my misunderstanding then. +1 to you.

Comment: Hopefully he meant from one table, not database.

Answer (score 2):

If the query in your question runs, then the problem is the data or your expectations.  The query:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
ORDER BY wallet_cash + bank_cash desc
LIMIT 4;
```

Should do what you want.  One obvious potential problem are `NULL` values.  If either value is `NULL`, then the expression will evaluate to `NULL`.  Perhaps this will work for you:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
ORDER BY coalesce(wallet_cash, 0) + coalesce(bank_cash, 0) desc
LIMIT 4;
```